# Is nginx responsible why I got an err_empty_response and err_connection_reset?

Tags: python-2.7, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am new to python flask web development, this is also my first time to deploy a flask application in other server came from other location and access it to my computer, at first glance I can successfully access the URL from my computer, oh, forgot to mention, my application is about file uploading of .xls file to the database, I intended to upload 7000+ records but the browser always giving me an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and sometimes ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when the application runs long, but when I tried to upload 1000-1300 records, it is successful. I am bothered because I can't replicate this error from my localhost run by **python manage.py runserver**, I got this error only when I access the application from other server which uses **gunicorn and nginx**. Hope you understand my english. This is my config setting for nginx:

```
server {
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try setting `client_max_body_size 0;` in your `location` directive to disable any size limits for uploaded files and also try adding `lingering_time 120s`.

Nginx will abort the upload process if the files are too big and a timeout appears. This will prevent your app from actually getting any data and throwing errors.

BTW: If the above works, I'd tune the values to something more reasonable.

More info on [client_max_body_size](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) and [lingering_time](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#lingering_time)

Comment: Thanks, already tried it but it's not working, still getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. However, I found a solution, I pip installed  `gevent` and used it as a worker class in `gunicorn`. But unfortunately didn't know how can I apply it in `supervisor` command variable, are you familiar with it?Thanks a lot